# At what speed do things stop being stable and essentially become atomic bomb?

Tags: speed-of-light, fusion

I know that when things go very fast (approaching the speed of light), they tend to turn into atomic bombs. What speed can you reach (in earth's atmosphere) before nuclear fusion begins. Does this speed vary with different materials and is so how much? What about in a vacuum, it seems like air resistance could be the problem.

Comment: This is a must: http://what-if.xkcd.com/1/

Answer (score 2):

You're totally misinformed... atomic bombs raise from an exponentially expanding interaction, where in Uranium, for examples, a neutron is fired initially, and each neutron hits another Uranium atom and releases another 3 neutrons, and the energy released grows exponentially to create a horrible explosion.

And about the speed you can reach, this depends very much on the object you're accelerating. If you're accelerating a subatomic particle (like a proton), the CERN accelerator can reach a very high speed (I guess something like 0.99999c); but if you try to accelerate a "car"... then I guess you can't go over a 1000 km/h whatever you do.

Of course, when you accelerate subatomic particles, you do this in vacuum. The behavior of atoms in non-vacuum systems is very complicated and depends on many factors like the "Mean Free Path".

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mean_free_path

About the max. velocity you can reach in atmosphere, this can be realized clasically with the concept of "Terminal Velocity". Read about it here:

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Terminal_velocity

Comment: This is just wrong. You don't take nuclear fusion into account.

Comment: @jinawee: You mean fission?

Comment: @BenCrowell I mean fusion. Air atoms don't have enough mass to fission.